# Code 117 when reading from csv-file clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

When I read data from a csv-file that I want to have in a table I've created I get the following:

```sh
cat main10.csv | tr '\r' '\n' | clickhouse-client -d main -q'INSERT into main_data  FORMAT CSVWithNames'


Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line
```

The csv-file is a large one with almost 170 columns.

Comment: you need to use format [CSVWithNames](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csvwithnames) instead of CSV: *INSERT into main_data  FORMAT CSVWithNames*

Comment: Well it gets closer to working I guess. Clumsy of me to not think about CSVWithNames. It is not exactly the data I used that I posted (just a small example) now I get the following: 
Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line.

Any ideas?

Comment: try this decision [How to fix with command line ---> Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line #7861](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7861)

Comment: cat main10.csv|tr '\r' '\n' |clickhouse-client--format_csv_delimeter=$'\x0B' -d leker1 -q'INSERT into main_data  FORMAT CSVWithNames'


This just gives me command not found. Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: try this one:   *cat main10.csv | tr '\r' '\n' | clickhouse-client -d leker1 -q'INSERT into main_data FORMAT CSVWithNames'*

Comment: unfortunately I still get Code:117 then.

Comment: could you look at log file */var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log* and provide the full description of occurred error?

Comment: I've added the description of the error now. It is weird that it says that the error is from 09:19 today though..

Comment: this is not the mistake that is needed, search for the latest error that contains *Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line* and don't cut it on right side

Comment: Can't find any code 117 in the error log.

Comment: sorry, it looks like this error proceeded by clickhouse-client, try this command to get more debug info: *cat main10.csv | tr '\r' '\n' | clickhouse-client -d leker1 -q'INSERT into main_data FORMAT CSVWithNames' --log-level trace --send_logs_level trace*

Comment: Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-client/config.xml'.
Connecting. Database: leker1. User: default
Connected to ClickHouse server version 20.3.7.
Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line

Uninitializing subsystem: Logging Subsystem.


I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: could you connect with https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212620/code-27-when-reading-from-csv-file-clickhouse

Comment: I need to have 20+ in reputation to use chatroom..

Comment: what is the size of csv-file? could you share it (if it is not private) to test?

Comment: check these issues - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/search?q=%22Expected+end+of+line%22&type=Issues

Comment: I can't share the csv-file. But it is a large one around 170 columns, I am working with a reduced version of the csv-file however (not all the rows).

Comment: --input_format_skip_unknown_fields arg                           Skip columns with unknown names from input data (it works for JSONEachRow, CSVWithNames, TSVWithNames and TSKV formats).
  --input_format_with_names_use_header arg                         For TSVWithNames and CSVWithNames input formats this controls whether format parser is to assume that column data appear in the input exactly as they are

Comment: Okay!! Where in the command line am I supposed to use that command? Right now I write as following:
cat main10.csv | tr '\r' '\n' | clickhouse-client -d main -q'INSERT into main_data  FORMAT CSVWithNames'.

Comment: all *--input_format_..*-options apply to *clickhouse-client*. Execute *clickhouse-client --help* to observe all available options - try to play with them.  It would be good to get the excerpt from real data where error reproduced.

Comment: It was some errors in my csv-file that I managed to figure out. Thank you guys for the help!